# Calculation on groups after group by with Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame that is grouped by 2 columns - Date And Client and I sum the amount so: 
`new_df = df.groupby(['Date',Client'])`

Now I get the following df:

```
             Sum
Date Client 
1/1   A      0.8
      B      0.2
1/2   A      0.1
      B      0.9
```

I want to be able to catch the fact that there is a high fluctuation between the ratio of 0.8 to 0.2 that changed to 0.1 to 0.9. What would be the most efficient way to do it? Also I can't access the Date and Client fields when I try to do

```
new_df[['Date','Client']]
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use [`pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.pct_change.html) or [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
new_df = df.groupby(['Date','Client'], as_index=False).sum()
print (new_df)
  Date Client  Sum
0  1/1      A  0.8
1  1/1      B  0.2
2  1/2      A  0.1
3  1/2      B  0.9

new_df['pct_change'] = new_df.groupby('Date')['Sum'].pct_change()
new_df['diff'] = new_df.groupby('Date')['Sum'].diff()
print (new_df)
  Date Client  Sum  pct_change  diff
0  1/1      A  0.8         NaN   NaN
1  1/1      B  0.2       -0.75  -0.6
2  1/2      A  0.1         NaN   NaN
3  1/2      B  0.9        8.00   0.8
```

Comment: Thanks, this is th direction but I want to know the difference in A ONLY vs. the differnece in B Only...?

Comment: If I understand correctly,  change column for groupby from `Date` to `Client` - `new_df['pct_change'] = new_df.groupby('Client')['Sum'].pct_change()`